# Insert "begin" after if statement in Emacs Verilog Mode

Tags: emacs, verilog, emacs24

I have been using Emacs to create and modify Verilog codes for some time now.
However, in Verilog mode, I am facing a small issue when I try to insert an "if" statement using the emacs command:

`C-c C-t ?`

The following is an example of how the statement is created in the above scenario:

```
if (a<b) begin
// the rest of the code
```

However I need emacs to insert the "begin" in the next line as shown below:

```
if (a<b)
begin
//rest of the code
```

After digging through the Verilog customization options available, I found one option named  `Verilog Indent Begin After If` which I think is supposed to produce the above effect. However toggling this option did not give my any visible changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just hack up your own command based on what you see in verilog-mode and add it to the keymap?

Comment: @pmr: Ya thats true but unfortunately I have no experience in lisp programming :( I was looking whether verilog mode had any direct options for the same. If not, I guess I will have to cook up something myself :/

Comment: I tried to provide you with everything you need. Have a look at the documentation of skeletons to understand them better. You probably want to stay away from the key-map part until you are a little more fluent in elisp. `C-h f` and `C-h v` are your friends.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will spend some time reading up on elisp as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code you will see that the function:

```
(define-skeleton verilog-sk-if
  "Insert a skeleton if statement."
  > "if (" '(verilog-sk-prompt-condition) & ")" " begin" \n
  > _ \n
  > (- verilog-indent-level-behavioral) "end " \n )
```

actually defines a skeleton. Just copy paste and add another line-break:

```
(define-skeleton my-verilog-sk-if
  "Insert a skeleton if statement."
  > "if (" '(verilog-sk-prompt-condition) & ")" \n " begin" \n
  > _ \n
  > (- verilog-indent-level-behavioral) "end " \n )
```

now we just need to hook our function over the old one in verilog-mode:

```
(add-hook 'verilog-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             ;; this is quite the hack because we don't respect
             ;; the usual prefix of verilog-mode but sufficient for us
             (define-key verilog-mode-map "\C-c\C-t?"
                         'my-verilog-sk-if)))
```

Comment: @event_jr Yes, that could be a replacement. Unfortunately, yas is not part of Emacs core and so core packages like verilog can not rely on it. Also, when you already have the boilerplate, why go and change anything? ;)